# Macro that executes a pivot table

Tags: macros, pivot

I've been working on a macro (with activex button) for about 5 hours. I need it to be able to automatically sort new data according to facility when it's added, and then to put it into a pivot and open new tabs with different facility data. I have ran into every compile error in the book. I've followed some advice and now I'm stuck on an error which says: `Run-Time error '9', Subscript out of range`. I am a beginner and so please forgive me if this is a less than intelligent question. I'm going to post the code.

```
'
' CreateWorkList Macro
' Create a work list by the facility
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+W
'
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$W$2897").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="2"
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$W$2897").AutoFilter Field:=2
    Range("C140").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 17
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 19
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 21
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 25
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 26
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 27
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 28
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 30
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 31
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 32
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 36
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 37
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 40
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 42
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 44
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 45
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 46
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 47
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 54
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 55
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 57
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 60
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 63
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 65
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 69
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 71
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 77
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 79
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 63
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("C1:W1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R135C21", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(1, 26).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=5
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Campus")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("OPID")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=6
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Campus")
        .PivotItems("Celebration").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("East Orlando").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Kissimmee").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Orlando").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("AcctNum"), "Sum of AcctNum", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of AcctNum")
        .Caption = "Counts of AcctNum"
        .Function = xlCount
    End With
    Range("AA10").Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
```

Next line is where I get the error:

```
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Altamonte"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("AB10").Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Apopka"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("AC10").Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Sheet1"
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "Winter Park"
    Range("C21").Select
```